# iOS simulator misplaces controls

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, ios-simulator

I am trying to learn iOS development, and have come across an issue with the iOS simulator. I created a new project (Single View App, only iPhone support) and only edited two things: the launch screen XIB and the storyboard.

I have attempted to make a login screen via the storyboard editor, and in the editor it looks like this:

[image: Storyboard]

I build and run it using the iOS simulator (iPhone 6), and then we have an issue:

[image]

The controls are all out of place. Why is this? I have tried changing the with and height of the storyboard editor (it started at: wAny hAny), but that did not work. How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: In the new Xcode versions, you need to layout the constraints of objects. On the same row as the any any option, theres a constraints options. This will allow you to customize and decide what the boundaries and distances between other objects and the superview of an object. To view /decide an object's constraints, click on the UILabel or UIButton and click on the constraints options. From there you'll start to understand what you have to do. Hope that kind of helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to read something about iOS auto layout and constraints.
Controls are misplaced, because you didn't set any rules, how they should be displayed, on different display sizes.
I recommend reading for example this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1